# SSIS & Business Objects SDK Error: File Repository Server Input is Down

Tags: sql, sdk, ssis, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

Has anyone accomplished pushing files to a BOE server using SSIS?  I am trying to develop a SQL Server 2008 SSIS package that will push report (Excel) files to our Business Objects Enterprise (BO XI 3.1) server.  Via a Script Task, I am using the  Business Objects .NET SDK components to authenticate and connect to the BOE Server.

I have a copy of the package deployed to a local instance of SQL Server 2008 running on my Windows XP desktop.  The package executes successfully (via a SQL Agent Job) and delivers the file to the designated location on the BOE server.

When I deploy the package to our development SQL server (SQL Server 2008 on Windows Server 2008 64-bit) and attempt to execute the package via a SQL Agent job, I receive the error message "File Repository Server Input is down" when the script task attempts to "Commit" the file to the BOE server.  The package is able to open a session with the BOE Server, create a new info object, but fails on the infoStore.Commit command.

I have another SSIS package that executes successfully from our development SQL server - it communicates with the BOE server and searches for user sessions.  It does not communicate with the Input File Repository - that seems to be the key distinction.

I have found limited information related to this error that indicates firewalls and ports between the SQL Server and BOE server may be the cause. I have reviewed the BOE Administrator's Guide to no avail (most likely due to my lack of understanding related to firewalls and ports). Both servers are within the same subnet and neither server has the firewall turned on.  The ports for the BOE CMS servers and the Input/Output File Repository servers have been set to static port ids.  Our network guy indicates there should be nothing preventing communication between the servers based on firewall or port settings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using the same account for both the SQL Agent job on your desktop (which is successfully committing the object) and the dev server (which is failing to commit)? Permissions issues are always high on my list of usual suspects when something works on my desktop but not on the server.

Comment: I am investigating that as a possible cause.  The SSIS package on my desktop is executed using my own AD account.  On the development SQL server, the SSIS package is executed via a SSIS Proxy using an AD account that has the same permissions as my account (both on SQL and on the BOE server).  I have requested to have a new proxy created that uses my AD account to see if I receive the same error.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried all the usual 'run as 32 bit' solutions? I guess yuor SDK is a 32 bit one, not a 64 bit one.

http://www.bidn.com/blogs/ShawnHarrison/ssis/2362/ssis-basics-running-a-package-in-32-bit-mode

However the fact the the SDK works for different services implies that it runs OK in 64 bit. So if you want to troubleshoot ports, I found this link http://scn.sap.com/thread/2027785 which indicates that the BOE ports are 6400 to 6411. To check that a given port is open, you go to a DOS prompt and type

```
TELNET hostname port
```

So if your BOE server is BOESERVER then you'd try this:

```
TELNET BOESERVER 6400
```

to test port 6400. You should get a black screen to indicate it's connected.

However, again, the fact that you seem to be able to connect and operate but not commit implies there is not a port problem as you can connect, just can't commit.

Are there any logs in the BOE side to give you a better idea of the issue?

Comment: I am able to telnet.  Those ports are for the BOE CMS server.  My package, because it's saving files to BOE, also needs to communicate with  the Input File Repository server.  I can telnet to all the ports for the CMS and I/OFRS.  I have not found anything useful in the logs.

Comment: So in the BOE logs, can you find the error you are describing?

Comment: No.  I have looked in the Event Viewer and have BOE CMS and FileServer traces turned on and there is nothing.

Comment: That's curious that your app reports and error but the error does not appear in BOE logs. I know nothing about BOE but usually and app will contain some indication of an error. Does it have any logs about the whatever steps occur before you commit?

Answer (score 0):

A resolution to this issue has been identified and verified.  The Windows AD account used by the proxy the SQL Agent job uses to execute the SSIS package did not have sufficient privileges on the network.  Our DBA gave the account local Windows administrator privileges on the SQL server and this resolved the "File Repository Server Input is down" error I was receiving.

Thanks to those who responded and gave me other ideas to investigate.